# Cut out number in files named after a pattern

Tags: regex, shell, unix, aix

I've got the following files:

```
create_file_1.sql
create_file_2.sql
create_file_3.sql
create_file_4.sql
```

I'm iterating those files in a loop.

Now I want to get the number inside those files. I want to store the `1`, `2`, `3`, … inside a variable in the loop.

How can I achieve this? How can I cut out this number?

P. S.: I want to achieve this with an AIX command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... It depends on how flexible you want it to be. If you can assume that the number is "the part between the second underscore and the first period after the second underscore", you can simply use:

```
NUMBER=$(echo $FILENAME | cut -d_ -f3 | cut -d. -f1)
```

assuming that `$FILENAME` holds the current filename, of course.

This uses `cut` to first take the string after the second underscore, then cutting that by taking the string leading up to the first period.

This, admittedly, does *not* use regular expressions which maybe you want based on your tags, but I find the above a bit easier to read for a simple case like this.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `sed`:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo "create_file_1.sql" | sed 's/.*_\([0-9]\+\)\.sql/\1/'
1
```

#### Using `bash`:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] var="create_file_1.sql"
[jaypal:~/Temp] tmp=${var%.*}  # Removes the extension
[jaypal:~/Temp] var=${tmp##*_} # Removes portion till the last underscore
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo $var
1
```

#### Using `awk`:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo "create_file_1.sql" | awk -v FS="[_.]" '{print $(NF-1)}'
1
```

Comment: When I execute your `sed` command, I get `create_file_1.sql` as the result.

Comment: @Tichodroma I am not so fond of `sed` but since that was one the tag I thought of offering it as a solution. `Bash` and `awk` versions is just show off!! ;)

Comment: @BernhardV Right, the back-references is `gnu` version. How about the `awk` or `bash`?

Answer (score 0):

```
for filename in create_file_1.sql create_file_2.sql create_file_3.sql create_file_4.sql
do
  i=$(echo $filename | cut -d_ -f3 | cut -d. -f1)
  # do something with $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only number in the file name is the one that you want to get this will also works

```
for filename in create_file_1.sql create_file_2.sql create_file_3.sql create_file_4.sql ; do
    number=`echo $filename | grep [0-9]* -o`
done
```

Comment: When executing `grep` with `-o` I get `grep: can't open -o`

Comment: strange... try with --only-matching but it's the same command